# Linux shell programming string compare syntax

Tags: linux, string, shell, compare

What is the difference between `=` and `==` to compare strings in Linux shell programming?

Maybe the following code works:

```
if [ "$NAME" = "user" ]
then
    echo "your name is user"
fi
```

But I think it's not a correct syntax. It would be used to compare string by `==` statement.

What is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These pages explain the various comparison operators in bash:

- http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/209/bournebash-shell-scripts-string-comparison/
- http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html
- http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html#ss11.2

On the second linked page, you will find:

```
==

    is equal to

    if [ "$a" == "$b" ]

    This is a synonym for =.
```

Comment: [This has come up before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links)

This comment was made before your several revisions on your answer

Comment: @Diarmaid I knew this would happen :). Is my answer rude? Maybe, sure, I just wasted my time reading a question that takes 10 seconds of Googling to find the answer to. Anyway, I also took the time to actually type a correct answer. So now the OP both got his answer and a gentle reminder to search first.

Comment: That first tech-recipes.com example did not work for me due to missing a semicolon (or newline?).

Comment: Is the idea of SO to provide something better than "10 seconds googling the answer"?

Comment: This answer itself is now one of the first hits on Google. This is why just answering "Google it." isn't always a good policy. StackOverflow has a really high page rank if you didn't notice.

Comment: Rude answer, considering the first results point to SO, are you trying to introduce an search-google infinite loop???

Comment: Worth noting, if it's a #!/bin/sh program, rather than a #!/bin/bash program, I can't use double equal signs on my 16.10 ubuntu server. I guess this is what John Giotta's comment about POSIX conformance hints at in his answer below.

Answer (score 23):

The single equal is correct

> string1 == string2
>
> string1 = string2
>
> True if the strings are equal. ‘=’ should be used with the test command for POSIX conformance

```
NAME="rafael"
USER="rafael"
if [ "$NAME" = "$USER" ]; then
    echo "Hello"
fi
```

Comment: Reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Answer (score 11):

In general, the = operator works the same as == when comparing strings.

Note:
The == comparison operator behaves differently within a double-brackets test than within single brackets.

```
[[ $a == z* ]]   # True if $a starts with an "z" (pattern matching).
[[ $a == "z*" ]] # True if $a is equal to z* (literal matching).

[ $a == z* ]     # File globbing and word splitting take place.
[ "$a" == "z*" ] # True if $a is equal to z* (literal matching).
```

source: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: Thanks for this! I was struggling with an issue where I'd used single square brackets instead of double.

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) or [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/Control_structures/comparison_operators.shtml). Personally, to compare strings, I use `case`

```
case "$string1" in
  "$string2" ) echo "matched";;
  *) echo "not matched";;
esac
```

I do not have to know which operator i should use