# Getting error with if condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What is wrong with my below script?

I am new to scripting and trying out simple scripts. I am getting an error with my script.

```
START_OUT = `grep -c "Start Report" jeevagan/test_scripts/log.txt`
FINISH_OUT = `grep -c "Finished Report" jeevagan/test_scripts/log.txt`
if [$START_OUT == $FINISH_OUT]
then
echo "All good"
else
echo "Warning!!!Monitor Logs"
fi
```

Comment: improper spaces in `if` i.e you must write `if [ "$START_OUT" == "$FINISH_OUT" ]`; always double quote your variables and use `$()` instead of backtick

Comment: What was your effort trying to fix the error?

Comment: "not working" can have many meanings, error thrown-----please provide the error, not the expected output--then provide expected output and actual output

Comment: @J.Chomel when you dont know what your error is, then how could it be dublicate... its not like a general question, that could be asked again.

Comment: @J.Chomel on that i will agree with you and you got a point, but that doesnt make it a dublicate still

Comment: I am getting the error like below:
START_OUT: command not found
FINISH_OUT: command not found

Comment: @hedgehog, let's just link it if you prefer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745303/linux-shell-programming-string-compare-syntax

Comment: @zeewagon did you fix the code as we said in the answers? also are you sure you run the script with bash? what are you writing in the terminal to start it??

Comment: @zeewagon check out my answer i put an update now for you to try something else....

Comment: @J.Chomel also this wasnt his only mistake, which you also didnt notice, he had a space on the variables declaration... so still not a dublicate :)

Comment: Get rid of the spaces around your `=`. Use, for example, `START_OUT=$(grep -c "Start Report" jeevagan/test_scripts/log.txt)`. `bash` doesn't want to see spaces around `=` when assigning shell variables.

Comment: This has the dubious honor of containing pretty much every newbie syntax mistake I can think of.  Instead of asking us humans to spend time on these things, try http://shellcheck.net/ until your code passes a basic lint.

Answer (score 2):

try leaving spaces on the if statement and add quotes on the variables, like this

```
if [ "$START_OUT" == "$FINISH_OUT" ]
```

If this is still not working try this exactly, this works for sure, if it still gives you an error, then use echo brefore the if statement and check what `$START_OUT` and `$FINISH_OUT` variables have stored, because the problem could be there, after you do this give us feedback:

```
 if  test "$START_OUT" = "$FINISH_OUT"
```

okayyyy, this was one of your problems, the other problem is that you left a space when you used grep and tried to add it in the variable...
i will rewrite your code, copy and paste it please. as you had it, it was like you calling the START_OUT command which obviously doesnt exist.... and tell me if it worked.

```
START_OUT=`grep -c "Start Report" jeevagan/test_scripts/log.txt`
FINISH_OUT=`grep -c "Finished Report" jeevagan/test_scripts/log.txt`
if  test "$START_OUT" = "$FINISH_OUT"
then
echo "All good"
else
echo "Warning!!!Monitor Logs"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

`bash/sh` is very space sensitive. You want

```
if [ $START_OUT == $FINISH_OUT ]
```

Note the spacing around the brackets. `"="` may be used instead of `"=="` for strict POSIX compliance. See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html#sect_07_01_01) for more details and note the comment

> In a script, the different parts of the if statement are usually
>   well-separated.

Comment: It is not working. I have tried leaving spaces

Answer (score 1):

`if [$START_OUT == $FINISH_OUT]` is wrong. take care about spaces. it should be like

`if [ $START_OUT == $FINISH_OUT ]`